# Process Builder not logging a call/creating a completed task

Tags: process-builder

[image]I am setting up email alerts using process builder.For each email that goes out, I want to log a call /create a completed activity saying the email was sent. I am using Create New Record for a scheduled action.  I am not sure why the task is not getting created under the object that is starting the process.  any ideas? Here is a screen shot. Do I need to say what object the task should go to when I add that action?

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your Task is getting created but only under the User under the `[Renewal__c].Regerstered...` field.

You are not assigning the Task to the object that started the process.  You need to assign the `Related To Id` to the Object that started the process.